# Why is the bandwidth for this QPSK system larger than expected?

Tags: gnuradio, qpsk

Below is my gnuradio-companion graph.

[image: graph]

As you can see the sample rate is 100k, I am modulating with QPSK, and am filtering the waveform (RRC) with the "Excess BW" parameter, at 0.35.  The spectrum is shown below:

[image: spectrum]

The bandwidth seems to be about 2*160kHz.  I would expect it to be about the baud rate, but it is far from that.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In gnuradio, the throttle block only determines the speed at which your computer is processing samples - it does not determine what the actual sample or baud rates are. As an example - consider that you generate random PSK symbols at 1 sample per symbol, and then upsample by 2 with a root raised cosine w/ 35% exccess BW so we're now at 2 samples per symbol (this is what the constellation modulator block does in your flowgraph). What is the absolute baudrate that you're running at? Answer: Whatever you want it to be. If I hook that I/Q stream up to an RF front end, I could theoretically transmit at any baud rate using those exact same samples. E.g. if the DAC is running at 1MSPS (assuming this is an I/Q DAC for simplicity like you might consider the ad9361) then my baud rate would be 1MSPS/(2 samples/symbol) = 500k symbols/sec. Assuming my PC could keep up (and I increased my throttle block so that my PC isn't slowing me down from producing samples), I could instead run the DAC at 10MSPS to transmit at 5M symbols/sec.

So - your question will probably be - how do I simulate a certain baud rate without a DAC/front-end? Well - it's whatever you choose it to be. In your flowgraph, you set the FFT sink to think that the sample rate is 500 kHz. The data you have hooked up to that sink is coming in at 2 samples/symbol, but factoring in the excess bw, the relative bandwidth will be about (1.35/2.0)*500e3 = 337.5 kHz which is exactly what the spectrum is showing you. If you did further upsampling and then looked at the FFT, the signal would appear narrower and vice versa.

Comment: yep, exactly. The "bandwidth" parameter in the GUI sink just defines the numbers written on the horizontal axis, and nothing else.

Comment: If the throttle block is not limiting the throughput of the graph to 100k samples / second (bandwidth suggests it's higher), what is the point of the throttle block?

Comment: Also both to you and @MarcusMüller - my impression was that the sink BW was as Marcus describes.  I just wanted to zoom out.  I don't expect it to have an effect on bandwidth of the signal.

Comment: The throttle block is simply limiting the speed that your computer is producing samples, in this case to approximately 100k samp/sec - but again, without sending them out to a D/A, these samples can represent any arbitrary rate you want. Maybe someone can come up with a more intuitive answer, I think it's a concept a lot of people trip up on.

Comment: Oh and if you want to 'zoom out' on your fft you need to increase your samples per symbol - either by increasing that from the constellation modulator block or by adding a subsequent interpolation stage.

Comment: I'd thought of the FFT bandwidth setting as a span, for visualization only. If that's not the case then several carriers spaced apart will not be visible?  Because if I increase the bandwidth I can view, it increases the bandwidth of the incoming signals as well!  Whereas with a spectrum analyzer for example, I can "zoom out" to view all the radio stations in the FM broadcast band.  That's what I was trying to do here, zoom out.

Comment: 1) the 'fft bandwidth' parameter as Marcus pointed out, is indeed only for visualization and simply sets the numbers on the scale. 2) You need to think about how a spectrum analyzer (SA) let's you 'zoom in/out'. There are a lot of techniques used like swept LO, or spectral stitching, etc. One very simplified example: say your SA has a controllable mixer followed by an ADC operating at a fixed sampling rate. When you zoom out, the mixer is moved across the whole band and FFT segments are computed along the way and then stitched together to form a wide capture.

Comment: @SafeCracker as said, no, that "bandwidth" number just sets the numbers on the axes. **No** block in GNU Radio knows or cares about actual frequency – all that matters is "how much of the nominal sampling rate is that?". For example, you set the Qt GUI sink "bandwidth" to 100 kHz, you have a tone at 1/10 of "official" sampling rate, it appears at 10 kHz. Same, identical siganl, you set the "bandwidth" to 1 MHz, the tone appears at 100 kHz. The GNU Radio "Getting Started" guide, linked on https://gnurardio.org explains all this!

Answer (score 0):

Your bitrate is 100 kbit/s

Your symbole rate is 50 ksymb/s (QPSK is 2 bits/symb)

Your sample rate is 100ksamp/s (at the input of the FTT or output of QPSK mapper, as you settle 2 samples per symbol in the constellation modulator)

I think you have an issue of scaling in your FFT plot because you set 500 KHz (-250 to 250 KHz in the x axis).

You should set 100k instead of 500kHz, and then your 0.35 is going to match on the plot